# login to firebase wtih 3 identfires ( user ID nomber + email + password )

Tags: java, database, firebase, authentication

I am building a project for my work company, I want it to be private login so only employees who belong to our company and have a unique work identifier number have the ability to sign in and log in.

I have added this question yesterday but now I am creating more clear one and adding my codes too as I was unable to edit the previous one.

the idea is to make a firebase check if the user has a valid id and email and password, and reject the login if the id number is not one of our company id numbers even if the email and password are correct.

I need it to be private depending on our work number which is 6 digits normally.
regards.

here are some codes

I posted the same question yesterday and Peter (Peter Haddad) tried to help me ( thanks for him ) and now I am posting this with a better build.

**Register.java**

```
package com.example.boc;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Date;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    EditText name,email,password;
    Button mRegisterbtn;
    TextView mLoginPageBack;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mdatabase;
    String named,emailed,passworded;
    ProgressDialog mDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        mRegisterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        mLoginPageBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        // for authentication using FirebaseAuth.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRegisterbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLoginPageBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    }

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        if (v==mRegisterbtn){
            UserRegister();
        }else if (v== mLoginPageBack){
        startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,login.class));
        }
    }

    private void UserRegister() {
        named = name.getText().toString().trim();
        emailed = email.getText().toString().trim();
        passworded = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(named)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailed)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passworded)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (passworded.length()<6){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Passwor must be greater then 6 digit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mDialog.setMessage("Creating User please wait...");
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailed,passworded).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    sendEmailVerification();
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    OnAuth(task.getResult().getUser());
                    mAuth.signOut();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"error on creating user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
//Email verification code using FirebaseUser object and using isSucccessful()function.
    private void sendEmailVerification() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user!=null){
            user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Check your Email for verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void OnAuth(FirebaseUser user) {
        createAnewUser(user.getUid());
    }

    private void createAnewUser(String uid) {
        User user = BuildNewuser();
        mdatabase.child(uid).setValue(user);
    }


    private User BuildNewuser(){
        return new User(
                getDisplayName(),
                getUserEmail(),
                new Date().getTime()
        );
    }

    private String getDisplayName() {
        return named;
    }

    private String getUserEmail() {
        return emailed;
    }

}
```

**my login.java**

```
package com.example.boc;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;


public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Email, Password;
    Button LogInButton, RegisterButton;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    String email, password;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    public static final String userEmail="";

    public static final String TAG="LOGIN";
    private Object Context;
    private Button button;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        LogInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        RegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (mUser != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"AuthStateChanged:Logout");
                }

            }
        };
        // LogInButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        //RegisterButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        //Adding click listener to log in button.
        LogInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Calling EditText is empty or no method.
                userSign();


            }
        });


        // Adding click listener to register button.
        RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Opening new user registration activity using intent on button click.
                Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Animatoo.animateDiagonal(login.this );


            }
        });

    }





    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //removeAuthSateListner is used  in onStart function just for checking purposes,it helps in logging you out.
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListner != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        login.super.finish();
    }



    private void userSign() {
        email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Enter the correct Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Enter the correct password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        dialog.setMessage("Loging in please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "Login not successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    checkIfEmailVerified();

                }
            }
        });

    }
    //This function helps in verifying whether the email is verified or not.
    private void checkIfEmailVerified(){
        FirebaseUser users=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        assert users != null;
        boolean emailVerified=users.isEmailVerified();

        {
            Email.getText().clear();

            Password.getText().clear();
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, DashboardActivity.class);

            // Sending Email to Dashboard Activity using intent.
            intent.putExtra(userEmail,email);
            startActivity(intent);
            Animatoo.animateInAndOut(login.this);


        }
    }}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with where your code is falling or where do you get exceptions? If any generated logs are there it should be easier for us to find out what is the solution to your problem.

Comment: The answer you received yesterday is really good. You should not post duplicate questions, instead edit your original question with updated information. If you are unable to edit, please contact SO Support [here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact). In your original question, you should include the code you've tried and also your Firebase Rules as that's what's going to be part of the solution.